# SQlite: The database file is locked (database is locked)

Tags: java, sqlite

I have create a simple gui in javafx which connects with a sqlite database. The purpose is to create a database of users and a database of questions as an simple QA game. Everything works fine. However after a while I am receiving the following weird problem, I got the following message:

> [SQLITE_BUSY]  The database file is locked (database is locked)

The game starts being slow and stuck some times. What is the reason of that error? Is this message due to that the database is always open? Sometimes I am closing the application I restart the game, however I am receiving again the message.

**EDIT:** Do I have to check the variable Connection?

```
Connection conQuestions= null, conUsers = null;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you making multiple connection to your database without closing them? If you are you should try implementing a check to see if only one connection is up.

To check if your database is open you can do:

```
if(yourConnection.isOpen()){
     doSomething(); //Maybe you want to close it here, if thats the case
     yourConnection.close();
}
```

Comment: yes it seems that I call PreparedStatement pst = gui.connectionQuestions.prepareStatement(sql); for every question.

Comment: That would not be a problem as long as the statements are created via the same connection.

Comment: Hmm the problem is not in the same session of the game but after some open and closing of the game. Is there a chance that the database is still open after the java game is over?

Comment: Could you maybe post some of your code so that we can see? It does sound like you are not properly closing your connection before exiting the program.

Comment: My code is really huge. However I think that I dont have something in my code in order to close the database.

Comment: Check out https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/close.html and see if that can help you. Usually you will want to close your connection when you no longer use it.

Comment: How can I check that the db is already open more that one time?

Comment: I edited my post, you can try that. When you close your program you might want to do this test, and close your connection aswell.

Comment: The really annoying problem, is that I am not getting this error the  most of the times. So I am not able to debug my code.